# How to rename a package in Eclipse with Subversive correctly?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I recently found some problems when I tried to rename a package in a Java project with Eclipse. I use Subversive for SVN integration.

If I rename a package via Refactor -> Rename, the commit fails.

I have to rename it in a somewhat strange way:

1. Create the new package as a new empty folder
2. Select all classes to rename
3. right click -> Team -> Switch
4. Enter new path.

After the commit, the rename is done, but very ugly.

How to do this on a nicer way?

Comment: Refactor -> Rename should work. What error message do you get during commit?

Comment: It said that the files are already in SVN.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/517752/403455).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read the Subversive documentation on **[Refactoring](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/refactor.php)**, you do have this warning:

> While refactoring, **the structure of the versioned folder is changed, so if it's not up-to-date the conflict while committing is inevitable**.
>   So the user must be sure, that he has updated the resource being refactored to the repository location revision.
>   Remember that the folder is considered to be not up-to-date even if only its revision number on the repository is changed.

It should work from Eclipse, but you need an up-to-date resource.

Comment: It's nice, if it should work but the error occured, even if I'm sure, the working copy was up-to-date.

Answer (score 4):

Niko's right.  Here's what I do when I want to rename a file within a project in Subclipse (subversion for Eclipse):

1. go to SVN Repositories, and "Rename/Move" the resource.
2. in the project perspective, right-click the recently renamed file and click "Team", "Update to Head".  The previously name file will disappear from the view but don't worry.
3. Right-click "Team", "Synchronize with Repository", and it will take you to the Synchronize perspective.
4. Right-click the properly named resoure and select "Update".  that's it

Answer (score 3):

you should rename/move the package first within svn (rightclick in svn explorer). then you update all the classes (you will get an error for each class that you can rightclick and solve)