# Rename and Refactor Class in Eclipse, and Keep SVN History

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, refactoring, history

When I rename a class in Eclipse (using Ctl-Shft-R on the class name), it also renames the class file, which is helpful. Unfortunately, with my Subclipse plugin for SVN, it commits this as an add of the new class file and a remove of the old class file, and subsequent use of that new file's history will not show the history of the original file.

This is a documented problem with Subclipse, and it will be fixed LATER (meaning possibly never). See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=213991 .

I used to do a little song and dance with Tortoise SVN and Eclipse, but I don't like doing it (even though I like Tortoise).

How can I do this without using two applications? How can I do this with as little fuss as possible?

Cheers!

Comment: :( I think the commit does indeed work! I realized that I was testing the history with Eclipse when it failed, would fix it with Tortoise, then test it with Tortoise (since it was open right in front of me). I just did a refactor in Eclispe, Ctrl-Shift-R, renamed a class, which renames the file too. I committed that change. When I look at the history and do a compare in Tortoise, it is fine. But when I do that in Eclipse, it doesn't follow the 'Copy from path' that Tortoise follows (and displays). So this is a problem, but not with committing...a problem with history browsing in Eclipse.

Comment: A good solution was provided by Álvaro González here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485928/how-to-rename-java-packages-without-breaking-subversion-history

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Subversive doesn't have this problem. Install Subversive rather than Subclipse.

Comment: I recall trying both Subclipse and Subversive last year or so, and deciding on Subclipse. I didn't make notes on why I went this way; there may have been trade offs or I may have had issues setting Subversion up.